# how to take 10 inputs from user in a single line in python3?

Tags: python-3.6

The user need to input space separated values and finally the enter button to submit.
I have tried the below code but can't restrict to only 10 inputs.
for eg- first ask for number of inputs. Then followed by the ten inputs whichare space separated in single line.

```
#input in single line separated by space(Python3).
n=int(input())    
a=[int(x) for x in input().split(), range(n))]
```

Comment: Add what you have tried, you will get better responses and more helpful replies if you show what you have attempted so far.

Answer (score 1):

Simply :

```
if len(a) != 10:
   print("len is not correct")
else:
   print("good")
```